# How to slice a string in Python in one step?

Tags: python-3.x, string, slice

Am new to Python.
"Hello World"[0:5][::-1] prints "olleH" as expected. I was wondering why "Hello World"[0:5:-1] is not doing the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you should start with a larger index and end with a smaller one in the case of a negative step. So the equivalent of your example is `"Hello World"[4::-1]`.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know that we have to start with higher index when using -1.

Comment: "Hello World"[4::-1] --> "olleH"
"Hello World"[4:0:-1] --> "olle"
What's the difference between 0 and no value?

Comment: @Vinay Indexing system of python always discards the last value. For instance, `(9, 4, 3, 5, 7)[1:4]` gives `(4, 3, 5)`, i.e. the first, the second, & the third values, not the forth one. (NB! that we count in order from the zeroth one). So if we specify the null index as the end, python will not take it. When we specify nothing `[4::-1]`, the median value is `None` in the fact.